# Error in creating procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PL/SQL function in Oracle cannot see DBMS_AQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378721/pl-sql-function-in-oracle-cannot-see-dbms-aq)

Below is my procedure to enqueue data in a queue, while running the procedure I am getting compilation errors, I can't find where I went wrong. Please help me with solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_enqueue(msg IN VARCHAR2)
AS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
enqueue_options dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
message_handle RAW(16);
BEGIN
dbms_aq.enqueue( queue_name => 'example_queue',
enqueue_options => enqueue_options,
message_properties => message_properties,
payload => message_type(msg),
msgid => message_handle);
COMMIT;
END;
```

ERRORS:

PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_AQ' must be declared

PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

when i try to use grant privilage, i am getting following error

ERROR
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

If that is the problem i ran the below pl/sql block to enqueue message, the procedure got successfully created.How is it possible if the privilage is not there?

```
DECLARE
enqueue_options dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
message_handle RAW(16);
message message_typ;

BEGIN
message := message_typ('NORMAL MESSAGE',
'enqueued to msg_queue first.');

dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name => 'msg_queue', 
enqueue_options => enqueue_options, 
message_properties => message_properties, 
payload => message, 
msgid => message_handle);

COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: see if you've granted privileges as mentioned in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that DBMS_AQ is not know. Since this is an Oracle package owned by SYS, it does exist. So you're missing the right to see and execute it.

Have you run

```
grant EXECUTE ON DBMS_AQ to appuser;
```

as explicitly shown in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13681124/413337) to one of your earlier questions?

Comment: I have edited my post, please check and give me the solution.

Comment: I am wondering after granting privilage also i am getting this error

PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_AQ' must be declared

Comment: The GRANT command must be run as SYS, which has sufficient privileges. If you still get `identifier 'DBMS_AQ' must be declared`, you haven't granted the privilege yet (or to the wrong user).

Comment: Ok thankyou the problem got resolved, I have one more query, i am  having an input parameter in the procedure i have created how to pass input to the arguments.I used "set_job_argument_value" but its throwing " invalid value 1 for attribute ARGUMENT_POSITION"

Answer (score 0):

check the DBMS_AQ pkg and find out which are the mandatory parameters for the procedure which u have used.

below queries 'll be useful for Queue's.

```
SELECT name, enqueue_enabled, dequeue_enabled
FROM user_queues;

SELECT owner, queue_name, queue_table, consumer_name
FROM dba_queue_subscribers;

SELECT queue_name, consumer_name, address, protocol, delivery_mode, queue_to_queue
FROM user_queue_subscribers;

SELECT qname, destination, start_date, start_time, propagation_window, next_time, latency
FROM user_queue_schedules;

SELECT qname, process_name, session_id, instance, last_run_date, last_run_time, current_start_date
FROM user_queue_schedules;

SELECT qname, current_start_time, next_run_date, next_run_time, total_time, total_number
FROM user_queue_schedules;

SELECT qname, total_bytes, max_number, max_bytes, avg_number, avg_size, avg_time
FROM user_queue_schedules;
```